# Variable not printing the entire value Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

If I assign something like
`process([[baby],[boy],[[is]dancing],[with],[[the][family]]],A)`,
then it gives output as

```
A = [[baby],[boy],[[is]dancing],[with],[[..][..]]].
```

I want it to show all the values on terminal.
Something like
`A = [[baby],[boy],[[is]dancing],[with],[[the][family]]].`

Comment: See [all these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[prolog-toplevel]+max_depth) answers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the toplevel is truncating the list when they are shown.
You can configure the depth of the maximum nesting with the prolog flag `toplevel_print_option`, with option `max_depth(0)`, with 0 meaning to show everything.

The helper procedure will modify the prolog flag to change only max_depth to 0, leaving the other options unchanged:

```
set_toplevel_flags:-
  current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, Opts),
  (select(max_depth(_), Opts, TOpts) -> NOpts=TOpts ; NOpts=Opts),
  set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, [max_depth(0)|NOpts]).
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `current_prolog_flag/2` predicate with the `toplevel_print_options` flag. Something like this:

> ```
> ?- current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, X).
>
> X = [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(10), spacing(next_argument)].
> ```

You can modify the `max_depth` option value, or alternatively you can type **w** after getting the abbreviated answer, and prolog will print the answer fully. Pressing **p** will restore the original format. To make the Prolog wait wor your input after printing the answer, you might want to add some non-determinism to the query by appending `; true.` to it. For more information see [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html).